# Use <select> filters with hidden columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

To show some data I use `.DataTable()` in the table I have 3 hidden columns but I need that on the top of my table appear the `<select>` filter for that 3 columns.

So first, is that posible using the datatables API? and if it is where can I get that info.

Right now I can get a `<select>` filter for the columns that my table shows but not for the hidden ones and only if I don't use `language: {url: "/js/Spanish.json",},` apparently if I use some translate file, the filter doesn't appear.

I check the 'Example - column filter' from here [datatable manual](https://www.datatables.net/manual/api) and this is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#TablaT').DataTable({
            info: false,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: false,
            scrollColapse: false,
            //searching: false,
            //ordering: true,
            order:[],
            language: {
                url: "/static/js/Spanish.json",
            },
            columnDefs:[
                {
                    targets: 'no-sort',
                    orderable: false,
                },
                {
                    targets: [5],
                    visible: false,
                },
                {
                    targets: [6],
                    visible: false,
                },
                {
                    targets: [7],
                    visible: false,
                },
            ],
        });

        table.columns().flatten().each(function(colIdx){
            //
            var select = $('<select />')
                .appendTo(
                    table.column(colIdx).footer()
                )
                .on('change', function(){
                    table
                        .column(colIdx)
                        .search($(this).val())
                        .draw();
                });
            //
            table
                .column(colIdx)
                .cache('search')
                .sort()
                .unique()
                .each(function(d){
                    select.append($('<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>'));
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** What is needed is 3 `<select>` filters from 3 columns, but the problem is that those 3 columns are hidden columns.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Also, can you provide sample markup?

Comment: Please specify the requirement clearly. This helps others to helps you.

Comment: I add what specifically need